# Jasmine - Globally available object

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I have a web site that I'm testing via [Jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/). My tests are spread across multiple JavaScript files. For that reason, I would like to have a JavaScript object that I can share across my tests. For example, I'd like to have the following JSON be available to all of the tests in my files.

```
var settings = {
  rootUrl: 'http://www.example.com',
  username: 'test'
};
```

Then, in my tests, I'd like to do something like the following:

**tests1.js**

```
describe('TestSet1', function() {
  it('Should load properly', function(done) {
    var url = settings.rootUrl + '/contact';
    // do stuff
  });
});
```

**tests2.js**

```
describe('TestSet2', function() {
  it('Should load properly', function(done) {
    var url = settings.rootUrl + '/login';
    // do stuff
  });
});
```

How do I get `settings` to be available across JavaScript test files? Where do I define `settings`? How do I import `settings` into my tests?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is node, you can require it in at the top of all the pages:

```
var settings = require('./settings.json');
```

If browser, you should be able to add a dependency above the test adding it to the global scope.

```
window.settings = {};
```

Answer (score 0):

In node.js you would `var settings = require('./settings');` at the beginning of your tests. Export the settings variable in the settings file:

```
var settings = {
  rootUrl: 'http://www.example.com',
  username: 'test'
};

module.exports = settings;
```

In browser you might just want to include the file with a script tag before you include your specs:

```
<!-- include spec files here... -->
<script src="spec/settings.js"></script>
<script src="spec/test1.js"></script>
<script src="spec/test2.js"></script>
```